# Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/MaterialTheme')

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to develop an object detection app in an android studio but it gives me an error.
the error is in this line `android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme"`

**`manifest.xml`**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme">

        <activity android:name="org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/activity_name_classification">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="org.tensorflow.demo.DetectorActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/activity_name_detection">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="org.tensorflow.demo.StylizeActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/activity_name_stylize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest
```

Comment: Have you checked `style.xml` file? Does it have the style mentioned?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri there is no file in location res/values/styles.xml it means i have to add it?

Comment: You can add the file and use any default theme that you want for all your activities unless you specify. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

Comment: @ShobhitPuri thank you

Comment: Let me know if that worked. Else you may try removing the attribute altogether if you don't need it.

Comment: i removed the attribute and it works thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give an answer which might be helpful to others coming on the question later. If you don't need any custom theme, then you can remove the attribute. Else create a `style.xml` if it doesn't already exist inside `res/values` and check if that particular `<style></style>` resource exists or not. If not, then you can create one. Hope this helps.